# Microsoft Graph SDK list subscribedskus not returning expected response

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a list of ConsumedUnits from the Microsoft Graph API using C# following this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscribedsku-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

I'm able to get the expected response when I hit the Graph Explorer, but try to hit it using the SDK/C# and console the response all it returns is

```
Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceSubscribedSkusCollectionPage
```

If anyone has an example how to pull ConsumedUnits from this endpoint through the SDK I'd love to see it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GraphServiceSubscribedSkusCollectionPage` has two properties:

`CurrentPage` which is an `IList<SubscribedSku>` and

`NextPageRequest` which is an `IGraphServiceSubscribedSkusCollectionRequest` used to get to the next page of items, if another page exists. This value will be null if there is not a next page.

Example how to get all items:

```
var items = new List<SubscribedSku>();
var subscribedSkus = await graphClient.SubscribedSkus
                                    .Request()
                                    .GetAsync();
items.AddRange(subscribedSkus.CurrentPage);
while (subscribedSkus.NextPageRequest != null)
{
    subscribedSkus = await subscribedSkus.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    items.AddRange(subscribedSkus.CurrentPage);
}
```

Resources:

[Collections](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/collections.md)